# Given $x^4+x^3+5x^2-x+M=0$ , find $M$ such that $X_1 +X_2=X_3\cdot X_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Given the polynomial equation $x^4+x^3+5x^2-x+M=0$, I am looking for the value of $M$ such that $X_1 +X_2=X_3\cdot X_4$, where $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ are the complex roots.

I have tried doing it with Vieta's formulas:
$$X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4 = -1$$
$$X_1X_2+X_1X_3+X_1X_4+X_2X_3+X_2X_4+X_3X_4=5$$
$$X_1X_2X_3+X_1X_2X_4+X_1X_3X_4+X_2X_3X_4=1$$
$$X_1X_2X_3X_4=M$$
and of course
$$X_1+X_2=X_3X_4$$
but I can't solve it... 
How do I go on from here?
Any tips ?

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What are the capital $X$s ?

Comment: Would OPs PLEASE write their questions the way they want it to be AT ONCE! The original formulation had the condition $X1 +X2=X1*X2$ so I was hiding away to some quiet place to spend time on it (and I solved it), only to find later that the condition was changed meanwhile to  $X_1 + X_2 = X_3 X_4$. Please do not waste my time.

Comment: @RobertZ: Your edit makes the question consistent, but I cannot see whether that is the originally intended version. (See comment by @Andreas)

Comment: @ccorn Yes, I hope that the OP will confirm my editing. Let's wait for a response form Simon Jachson

Comment: @Simon Jachson Do you mind to confirm that the edited question is what you intended in the original question?

Comment: It is pretty annoying that the OP hasn't confirmed what his question is.

Comment: @Andreas  All the more the reason to downvote the question, perhaps even to vote to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Let $p=cd$ and $s=c+d$, then from the Vieta's formulas and the given equation $a+b=p$ we obtain
$$p+s=-1,\quad\frac{M}{p}+p+sp=5,\quad \frac{Ms}{p}+p^2=1.$$
After eliminating $s$, we get
$$\frac{M}{p}-p^2=5,\quad-\frac{M}{p}-M+p^2=1\implies M=-1-5=-6.$$

Comment: p = cd and also  s=cd ?

Comment: Since this deduction is $\implies$ only, a verification step should be added. With $M=-6$ the polynomial is $(x^2+x+6)(x-1)(x+1)$ and indeed the sum of the quadratic roots equals $(+1)\cdot(-1)$.

Comment: @ccorn Yes, I agree, a verification step is needed.

Comment: Graphically, I found that $M = -6$ is correct.